# Audit logging nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, logging, audit

could you provide some samples for audit loggin using NHibernate (ASP.Net+C# codd, not java code)

Answer (score 5):

[Event Listeners](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-events) are better for audit info than Interceptors. [Here's a great example](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/29/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-amp-ipreinserteventlistener.aspx) from [Ayende's blog](http://ayende.com/Blog/Default.aspx).

Comment: One caveat that I discovered when using Ayende's solution: it only works using static updates, not dynamic. This was true up until NH 3.0, not sure about 3.1 and 3.2. This has been documented in a couple of places: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087888/ipreupdateeventlistener-and-dynamic-update-true and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383420/nhibernate-preupdate-event-listener-not-persisting-changes

Answer (score 1):

I've most often seen this done with interceptors. There are plenty of blog postings to be found through Google about implementing interceptors for auditing, like [this one](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/rhouston/archive/2008/03/27/creating-a-timestamp-interceptor-in-nhibernate.aspx).