# Audit info in base class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nhibernate

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC3 application using NHIBERNATE. I have a base class **Entity** that is used to capture some audit information like CreatedBy, CreatedOn, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn, etc. These properties should get populated automagically whenever a derived class is created and persisted/updated.

As the **Entity** type and all other types are defined in the **DOMAIN** Assembly, What would be the best way to percolate **USER** information from **Web** project to **DOMAIN** to populate the information in **Entity** base class

### EDIT

Further,

1. Currently, i define all properties as **public virtual**, so how do I implement them so that the dates/userId are created on the fly at the time of persistence.
2. I want Base class properties to persist in each table for derived concrete classes (table per concrete class). How do i specify it using FLUENT NHIBERNATE (I am not using Automapping)

Comment: Hey all geniuses out there, please help. I am sure it's a very usual scenario for usually all applications.

Comment: There are lots of examples on Google: "nhibernate audit interceptor". There are simpler examples than Martin's below. You can also use event listeners. Couple of things to be aware of: 1) you have to update the state collection of the entity because that is what is persisted. See  'state[i]' in Martin's sample; 2) if you have set NHibernate to use dynamic sql there is a bug that stops it seeing your changes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383420/nhibernate-preupdate-event-listener-not-persisting-changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an Interceptor when you open the session:

```
sessionFactory.OpenSession(new AuditInterceptor());
```

File: AuditInterceptor.cs

```
using System;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Type;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security;

namespace bla
{
    /// <summary>
    /// NHibernate Interceptor that stores audit information (idlogin and datetime.now) on every save and update
    /// </summary>
    public class AuditInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
    {

        private int updates;
        private int creates;
        private int loads;
        private ISession session;

        public override void OnDelete(object entity,
                                      object id,
                                      object[] state,
                                      string[] propertyNames,
                                      IType[] types)
        {
            // do nothing
        }

        public override bool OnFlushDirty(object obj, object id, object[] currentState, object[] previousState, string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
        {
            bool found = false;
            if (obj is Entity)
            {
                updates++;
                for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.Length; i++)
                {
                    if ("dtlastchanged".Equals(propertyNames[i].ToLower()))
                    {
                        currentState[i] = DateTime.Now;
                        found = true;
                    }
                    if ("lastchangedby".Equals(propertyNames[i].ToLower()))
                    {
                        currentState[i] = this.session.Get<Login>(IdLogin, LockMode.None);
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return found;
        }

        public override bool OnLoad(object obj, object id, object[] state, string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
        {
            if (obj is Entity)
            {
                loads++;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public override bool OnSave(object entity,
                                    object id,
        object[] state,
        string[] propertyNames,
        IType[] types)
        {
            bool found = false;
            if (entity is Entity)
            {
                creates++;
                for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.Length; i++)
                {
                    if ("dtlastchanged".Equals(propertyNames[i].ToLower()))
                    {
                        state[i] = DateTime.Now;
                        found = true;
                    }
                    if ("lastchangedby".Equals(propertyNames[i].ToLower()) && !(entity is Login && (entity as Login).IsInVerification))
                    {
                        state[i] = this.session.Get<Login>(IdLogin, LockMode.None);
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return found;
        }

        public override void AfterTransactionCompletion(ITransaction tx)
        {
            //if (tx.WasCommitted)
            //{
            //    System.Console.WriteLine("Creations: " + creates + ", Updates: " + updates, "Loads: " + loads);
            //}
            updates = 0;
            creates = 0;
            loads = 0;
        }

        public override void SetSession(ISession session)
        {
            this.session = session;
            base.SetSession(session);
        }

        protected long IdLogin
        {
            get
            {
                return (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as CustomIdentity).IdLogin; // or something else that holds the id of the current logged in user
            }
        }
    }
}
```